# Meteor Methods insert not working (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, insert

I am trying to write a table with various numbers of rows and columns to a database. For this, I have a `Criterion` collection that saves the table headers and an `Option` collection that saves the table data.

The structure is like this:

- for `Criterion`:

  `{
      { "_id" : "hId1", "name" : "Option Name", "tableId" : "tId1" },
      { "_id" : "hId2", "name" : "Rent", "score" : 9, "tableId" : "tId1" }, 
      { "_id" : "hId3", "name" : "Surface", "score" : 5, "tableId" : "tId1" }, 
      { "_id" : "hId4", "name" : "Price", "score" : 5, "tableId" : "tId1" },
      { "_id" : "hId5", "name" : "CPU", "score" : 5, "tableId" : "tId4" } 
      etc.
  }`
- for `Option`:

  `{
      { "_id" : "id1", "score" : 5,
          "hId1" : { "value" : "Apt 1" },
          "hId2" : { "value" : "800 sqft", "score" : 1 }, 
          "hId3" : { "value" : "$800", "score" : 3 }, 
          etc.
          "tableId" : "tId1" 
      }
      { "_id" : "id2", "score" : 5,
          "hId1" : { "value" : "Apt 2" }, 
          "hId2" : { "value" : "780 sqft", "score" : 10 }, 
          "hId3" : { "value" : "$700", "score" : 3 }, 
          etc.
          "tableId" : "tId1" 
      }
      etc.
  }`

The first row for `Criterion` will always have `"Option Name"`. For the data above, the table with `"tableId" = "tId1"` would end up looking like this (`tableId` and `headerId` are the keys):

```
| Option Name | Surface  | Price |
| =========== | ======== | ===== |
| Apt 1       | 800 sqft | $800  |
| Apt 2       | 780 sqft | $700  |
```

My code looks like this (`imports/api/comparison.js`):

```
/**
 * Options are for the rows
 */
export var Option = new Mongo.Collection('option');

/**
 * Criteria are the columns 
 */
export var Criterion = new Mongo.Collection('criterion');

Meteor.methods({
    'comparison.insertRow' (query, headerId, tableId, isFirst) {
        check(query, Object);
        check(headerId, String);
        check(tableId, String);
        check(isFirst, Boolean);

        if(isFirst){
            var data = {};
            data._id = headerId;
            data.tableId = tableId;
            data.name =  "Option Name";
            Criterion.insert(data);
        }

        query._id = tableId;
        Option.insert(query);
    },
});
```

Where `isFirst` is a boolean expressing whether this is the first row in a table or not.

My query is constructed like this (`imports/ui/Menu/DataInsert.jsx`):

```
    var query = {};
    query.score = // value
    // get the header separately
    query[headerId] = {
        value: //valueH from form
    };

    // Find the text field via the React ref
    for (var i = 1, len = cols.length; i < len; i++) {
        query[cols[i]._id] = {
            value: //valueV from form,
            score: //valueS from form
        };
    }
```

My files are available on the server because I am doing this in `server/main.js`: `import '../imports/api/comparison.js';`

The `query` gets inserted no problem into `Option` no problem.

Why isn't `data` getting inserted into `Criterion` (when `isFirst = true`)?

I did a `console.log(data)` and a `console.log(query)` and it looks like this:
[image: Devtools picture]

whereas the data in the db looks like this:
[image: Terminal picture]

Comment: It might be because you are manually setting the _id field before inserting.  You should add a callback as the 2nd arg to Criterion.insert which accepts an error object as the first arg.  Use that to check if the insert is throwing an error.  Read the **on server** portion of the [api](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-insert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jordanwillis was correct above, this was happening because I was setting the `_id` manually on the `query`. I did need to set the id, but I needed to set the `tableId`.

So, for the record, this is what I did:

```
'comparison.insertRow' (query, headerId, tableId, isFirst) {
    check(query, Object);
    check(headerId, String);
    check(tableId, String);
    check(isFirst, Boolean);

    if(isFirst){
        var data = {};
        data._id = headerId;
        data.tableId = tableId;
        data.name =  "Option Name";
        Criterion.insert(data);
    }

    query.tableId = tableId;
    Option.insert(query);
},
```

And my foreign keys are `tableId` and `headerId` (which is part of `query`).